# Add dots between pagination numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I'm working on pagination on a website, i make everything work properly but i can't understand the behaviour (and therefore implementation) of pagination's numbers display with dots.
Right now i display all my numbers in a list and give active class if is the current page liek this:

```
displayNumbers : function(numbPages, page){
            let pagEl = jQuery('.pagination__list');
            pagEl.empty();

            for( let i = 1; i <= numbPages; i++){
                let pageNumb = i;

                if(pageNumb === page) {
                    jQuery(pagEl).append(`<li class="active" data-numb="${pageNumb}">${pageNumb}</li>`);
                } else {
                    jQuery(pagEl).append(`<li data-numb="${pageNumb}">${pageNumb}</li>`);
                }
            }
        },
```

The function is called like that:

```
app.pagination.displayNumbers(app.numbPages, page);
```

Where `app.numbPages` is a Number of how many pages i have in total and `page` is the current page.

What i would like to implement is something like:

`1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 28 | 29 | 30`

But how is the behaviour? I also have hard time to find examples since nowday site mostly use infinite scrolling.
Anyway i guess i will have something like:

`1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |... | 29 | 30`

But what's happen if i have page 8 for examples?

`... | 6 | 7 | 8 | ... | 29 | 30`
or maybe

`1 | 2| ... | 7 | 8 | ... | 29 | 30`
I don't liek any of these, i would like to stick with max 1 `...` but if this is how is usually done, i will do it.

And of'course any implementation hints (plain javascript or jquery) is super welcome

Comment: I think this question would be a better fit for https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @giargiaSambrotta have a look this example , i think its related to your requirements https://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/#page-1

Comment: @Lioness that's a nice solutions!! I like! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Most sites don't do multiple ..., the use < and > on the ends to show that there are more pages available.

So instead of: 
`... | 6 | 7 | 8 | ... | 29 | 30`

it would be 
`< | 6 | 7 | 8 | ... | 29 | 30`

Some sites also use double arrows (<< and >>) on the very end, which denotes the ability to skip first or last page. While usually showing, these can be greyed out when unavailable.

`<< | < | 6 | 7 | 8 | ... | 29 | 30 | >>`

Comment: cool thanks then let's say i always display 5 numbers with `...` in the middle. If i reach more then 3 numbers at the beginning, i show `<` at the beginning and i slide up all the numbers in the array of 1. Not sure how to do "slide" part tho.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everybody for your suggestions.
I ended up using a plugin since there are just too many little things to take care which i don't have the time to do and I also feel not so smart to re-invent the wheel.

If you need standard pagination i found [simplePagination](https://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/) quite good.
Is simple enough, you can customize your css as you wish but you don't have access to your html.

There is one function `onPageClick` that control everything happen when a new page is displayed (so new page, next, prev).
I easily integrated in already done OOP code.

Hopefully this is helpful for someone else.